# "Please be careful about what you said"

Tags: formal-language, email

I have a rude student who wrote me a rude email with full sentence in capital. And she said to me that I am trying to challenge her because I did not extend the homework time for her (20 students do the job, perfectly).

I response to her by this:

I do not want to argue more than that. I help you more than 5 times.

"Please be careful about what you said". I just try to stop her communicate with me like that and do not saying wrong information about me.

My question is, does my response can be interpreted as a threat?

If this question is not belong here, please advice me for a more appropriate tag.

Comment: If it's advice not to send emails like that in future, "Please be careful about what you _say_" would be better. We're not  supposed to do proofreading, but you should say "I have [already] helped you more than 5 times".

Comment: If the student is angry, she could claim anything is a threat. It sounds to me like you were polite, but in emails like this one it might be better to explain exactly what you mean. Avoid arguing or trying to make the other person do something, just state the facts. Imagine somebody else is reading it - you want them to understand what you're saying, and why you're saying it. If there are any problems in future, your emails are a record of what happened and how each side responded.